# How to bind the li element to an id inside ng-repeat to display different images for different li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

This is my html code

```
<ul class="steps-indicator">
    <li ng-repeat="step in steps">
        <a ng-click="goTo(step)">{{step.title || step.wzTitle}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this is my css :

```
.steps-indicator li a:before{
    content:url('/img/wizard-arrow.png') no-repeat;
}
```

The thing i am trying to achieve here is to show different images in front of different anchor elements.

I am using the angular-wizard in ionic for mobile, and customizing the look and feel of the progress bar element. Here is the link http://mgonto.github.io/angular-wizard/

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I think i missread your question. Is that what you need?

Put all the images inside the "step.images" and display this all doing an ng-repeat again.

```
<ul class="steps-indicator">
    <li ng-repeat="step in steps">
        <img ng-src="{{img}}" ng-repeat="img in step.images" />
        <a ng-click="goTo(step)">{{step.title || step.wzTitle}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If you only have 1 image per "step" you don't need to use ng-repeat anymore for the image.

```
<ul class="steps-indicator">
    <li ng-repeat="step in steps">
        <img ng-src="{{step.image}}" />
        <a ng-click="goTo(step)">{{step.title || step.wzTitle}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then just modify your css to show it as you like.

Is that what you need?

Comment: i need to display different images before each <a> and there is only 1 a in the ng-repeat

Comment: Sorry , but that didn't solve it but was an interesting view i didn't think. What is need is something like this [IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/dr72b4.png[/IMG]

Comment: Maybe if you do a live preview with plnkr.co or something like this we can help you with what you have and what you need.

Comment: I am a bit new to angular could you please show how to "Put all the images inside the "step.images" and display this all doing an ng-repeat again." @nada